# PDF to TIFF - with JPEG Compression

Tags: ghostscript

I have Color PDF's.   Trying to convert them to Color TIFF's.
My IBM DaejaViewer is very particular on the compression that it can display.

I would like to use the TIFF compression of "JPEG", as that is supported by IBM DaejaViewer.

Is this conversion method supported in Ghostscript and if so what are the "-sDEVICE=" value and the "-sCompression=" value?

Answer (score 0):

No, Ghostscript's TIFF output does not support JPEG compression. We could probably add it but, frankly, (on a personal level) I've always been opposed to lossy compression in TIFF. If you feel strongly we should support it, you can open an enhancement request at https:/bugs.ghostscript.com

Parenthetically, I find it very strange that DaejaViewer would support TIFF with JPEG compression, but not JFIF....

Comment: JFIF is supported by DaejaViewer.  We have a custom application that needs the images to be stored as Color TIFF's.  So I am trying to find a supported Ghostscript TIFF compression, and a supported DaejaViewer TIFF compression, and make it work.

Comment: For contone tiff, gs supports LZW and PACKBITS compression.